# How can I restrict outbound connection to a single domain name?

Tags: iptables, firewall, nftables

I would like to restrict the outbound access of my device to a single domain name, let's say abc.com. How can I do that?

Device needs to resolve the domain name to an IP address which might change depending on the server load. I am ok with allowing DNS access + a single domain.

Seems like iptables can accept hostname but that wouldn't be dynamic in case the IP address of the hostname changes. I don't even know if there is a hostname support in nftables.

I was wondering what options do I have.

Comment: You may be aware of this already, but it's worth mentioning that some websites are hosted behind a DNS load balance.  This may mean that each time a client requests an IP they will be given a different IP address.  Caching in the client will slow down the change but such websites would make this type of limit pretty tricky.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point:

```
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Then you add this crontab job (you can run it every minute if you desire):

```
#! /bin/bash

dig +short abc.com | while read address; do
    if [ -z "`/sbin/iptables-save | grep "$address"`" ]; then
        /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -d "$address" -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80  -j ACCEPT
        /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -d "$address" -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
    fi
done
```

This is totally untested but should work.